# Why does Neovim not allow me to run an IPython embed when I run it in a shell?

Tags: vim, neovim

In my init.vim for Neovim, I have the same line as in my .vimrc in Vim, which, when pressing F12, runs the file currently in the buffer using the python3 interpreter:

`autocmd FileType python nnoremap <silent> <F12> :!clear;python3 %<CR>`

Now I'm trying to run this tiny "test.py" script by pressing F12 in normal mode:

```
import IPython
IPython.embed()
```

Works fine in Vim:

[image]

But doesn't work in neovim despite exactly the same line in my ~/config/nvim/init.vim:

[image]

So it does run IPython, but then immediately (red arrow) inexplicably asks if I want to exit. It's also got a bunch of weird escape sequences inserted (yellow arrow) which I suspect are the reason why it wants to exit, and which don't appear with normal vim.

I don't really like the internal neovim terminal, so how can I get neovim to behave exactly like vim in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known limitation of NeoVim, `:!` is non-interactive and it will not allocate a pseudo-terminal which is typically required for full-screen applications such as IPython to run properly.

See [issue #1496](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1496) for details.

An alternative is to use NeoVim's (or Vim 8's) support for terminal, with the `:terminal` command, or with a function such aa `termopen()` (in NeoVim) or `term_start()` (in Vim 8) to run full-screen applications such as IPython.

In your case, something as simple as `:term python3 %`, running the command in a terminal in a split, might be an adequate replacement.

You might also find the [vim-bang-terminal](https://github.com/janlazo/vim-bang-terminal) plug-in interesting. It replaces a `:!` command with a similar command invocation that runs inside a Vim/NeoVim terminal instead.

Comment: Actually I found that running `:term python3 %` works fine now for my purposes so it's not as bad as I thought.

Comment: @ThomasBrowne Thanks for the feedback! I incorporated that direct suggestion into the answer. Indeed, while not exactly the same as the `:!` command, it's a great direct replacement for it.